# After cleaning symfony3 cache I get permission error

Tags: php, linux, symfony, ubuntu, chmod

I'm using LEMP stack (PHP 7) on ubuntu 16.10, and after cleaning Symfony 3 cach `php bin/console cache:clear` I'm getting error after refreshing site:

> RuntimeException in ClassCollectionLoader.php line 248:
>   Failed to write cache file "/var/www/html/mywebsite/var/cache/dev/classes.php".

and every time I have to do `chmod 777` commands manually to make it work again.
So what I have to do not to make `chmod`'s after cleaning cache each time, are there any solutions to to it once?

Comment: Your webserver probably runs under another user (www-data for example) than you're using to clear the cache. Add them to the same system group, use facl or clear the cache using the same user as the webserver runs.

Comment: Take a look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html  Point 3 should work for you.

Comment: Try this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297417/unable-to-write-cache-symfony2