# Symfony, cache error on app_dev.php, and error 500 on app.php

Tags: apache, symfony

If I try to load directly:
www.myappurl.com/app_dev.php
I have the error:

```
RuntimeException in ClassCollectionLoader.php line 239:
Failed to write cache file "/var/www/html/myapp/app/cache/dev/classes.php".
```

If I try to 
www.myappurl.com/app.php
I got an 500 error with a blank page.

When I try to load just "www.myappurl.com" it just load the default Apache testing page, saying all is ok, but it doens't redirection to app.php

I've tried everything from

[symfony2 : failed to write cache directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211829/symfony2-failed-to-write-cache-directory)

and

[Unable to write cache symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297417/unable-to-write-cache-symfony2)

I did all that says here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions

I've made an exact copy from another server to this one, same config, but here I can't load the app.php.

Any help?

EDIT: This is httpd.conf:
https://pastebin.com/dH27ZU2U

Comment: Did you try deleting the whole cache directory before running the cache:clear command?

Comment: Can you show your Apache config, just the relevant sections.

Comment: @dbrumann I've just did it, no difference. Alvin Bunk, ok, I edited my question with a link of httpd.conf

Comment: Which version of PHP and Symfony are you using?

Comment: @dbrumann PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2017 07:57:06). Symfony version 2.8.2. Could be a permisson setted in some superior .htaccess? My .htaccess in /web isn't reconigzed because it is not realoding by default to 'app.php' when I try to enter the url of my app.

Answer (score 0):

1. The cache error: I had a similar issue and was able to resolve it by ensuring that I had the correct ACL (Access Control List) permissions set. You can investigate your ACL settings by navigating to the directory in question via terminal (if you are using a mac) or some other command line tool and running the command "ls -l". You should see something similar to this next to your file name: "-rw-r--r--+" If you do not see the '+' symbol, then your ACL permissions are not set up properly. Rerun the permissions commands from https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html with the addition of -R to apply the permission to all existing files targeting the cache directory specifically. This worked for me, I hope that it helps you.

*These Commands are for Symfony 3. If you are using Symfony 2, please update directory var/cache to app/cache*

> HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)
>
> sudo chmod -R +a "$HTTPDUSER allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" var/cache
>
> sudo chmod -R +a "$(whoami) allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" var/cache

2. The app.php error: It's hard to tell what the issue is without more information, but here are a few suggestions that I can make based on what I see posted:

   - Update line 164 in your httpd.conf to this "DirectoryIndex index.html
     app.php" and restart apache. This will allow apache to read your app.php file without writing app.php explicitly in your url. www.myappurl.com
   - Make sure that you have deleted or changed the permissions of app.php file in your project. The file should be located in the web folder and the permission should be -rw-r--r-- (find this by running ls -l command)

Hope that this helps!